# How do I parse a date string which may be in two different date formats and display it to local time in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, datetime, nsdateformatter, utc

I’m getting a date string in two different time formats as the following:

`yyyy-MM-dd’T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z’` like `2015-03-05T05:57:58.854Z` and `yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` like `2015-03-05T11:27:58 +0530`.

I have to parse the string and display the time in the local timezone. How do I parse a date string which may be in two different date formats and display it to local time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with parsing with a format first, if the it gives you a date object, use that, otherwise use the other format. A rough draft for iOS will be as follow:

```
NSDate* dateFromString(NSString *string){
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //try with first format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    //convert the date
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];

    //check if the first format worked or not
    if (!date) {
        //try with the other format.
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
        //return the converted date
        return [formatter dateFromString:string];
    }
    return date;
}
```

You'll be calling it like this:

```
NSDate *aDate = dateFromString( @"2015-03-05T05:57:58.854Z");
NSDate *anotherDate =dateFromString( @"2015-03-05T11:27:58 +0530");
```

Use the same technique for android.